# Not receiving notification on Moto E4 plus

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, motorola

One of the client is using our application which is a video calling application on Moto E4 plus device. We show up the Calling screen when we get the FCM push notification from server. So for this particular device she's not getting the call when application is in Background or Killed. She didn't check if it's working when application is running in foreground.

Below is the code we use in FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("FirebaseMessaging", "onMessageReceived");
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppConstants.INCOMING_CALL_BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sendImplicitBroadcast(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, 
intent);
}


private static void sendImplicitBroadcast(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    PackageManager pm = ctxt.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(i, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : matches) {
        Intent explicit = new Intent(i);
        ComponentName cn =
                new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

        explicit.setComponent(cn);
        ctxt.sendBroadcast(explicit);
    }
}
```

We have below is the gradle setup.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.videocallapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 48
        versionName "2.2"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

We have noticed that when Autostart settings is turned off, service class is not able to open application. But need to be sure before we pitch this to client.